# How to grab the contents in a beautiful soup tag list?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<a href="thisisaurl.html" data-id="7083608062" class="result-title hdrlnk">A table</a>
```

There is an entire webpage of these  tags that I am trying the grab the text from.  In this instance, it is "A table".  So far I can get a list of these blocks of html like the one above using `item_title = soup.findAll("a", "result-title")`  I can't seem to figure out how to narrow it down so I just have a list like ["A table", A chair", . . .] etc. from these blocks of html.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `string` property of a tag to get the string that's inside the tag.

```
items = [a_tag.string for a_tag in item_title]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Can you explain the a_tag part?  I understand you are looping through the items but could a_tag hold any name or does it have to be a_tag according to beautiful soup?

Comment: The a_tag part is just a `variable` name of your choosing. The way the `list` is created is using `list comprehension`. A `for loop` with an `append` to a `list` would give you the same result. For what it's worth I would change the item_title `variable` name to a_tags to be more representative of what it is. A `list` of a_tag items.